# Recommended fuel for Honda Fit Sport 2008

Tags: honda, gasoline, octane, fit

I recently bought a Honda Fit 2008, and I want to know what is the recommended fuel for my car?

In my country the gas stations sell "Regular" and "Superior" gasoline.

The Owners Manual recommends to use gasoline with octane 87 or higher.  Regular is supposed to have octane number 88 and Superior is supposed to have octane number 95.

I don't know what is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a loot at [this Q&A about the octane](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/862/difference-between-high-octane-and-low-octane). For your car, I'd say go with whatever the manufacturer says. They say "87+" then 88 will run fine. There are factors other than the octane rating that come into play with the question "which is better..." so I hesitate to get too far into that.

In my personal experience, I have found that I get better fuel economy from "Premium" (91 Octane in California) fuel, but I will also notice a huge difference between the gas company that I decide to use. (NOTE: This is also *much* more noticeable with my 296cc motorcycle than any var I've done the test with.)

My best advice is to do your study, test each, and choose the one that seems to most benefit you and your vehicle. Running a couple tanks of different gas won't do any harm (***as long as it's within the manufacturer's spec - don't use something like diesel or jet fuel!!!***), so you can test both and see what your car prefers. :)

Answer (score 3):

Which country do you live in?  The gas station should specify whether they are quoting RON or R+M octane.  And which market was the car originally sold for?

For example: In the U.S., [octane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating) is specified using R+M, which is what the manual is likely specifying unless it explicitly says otherwise.  If your gas station is selling gasoline that only provides 88 RON then the R+M octane would be below the 87 minimum specified by the car manufacturer, in which case you should fuel it with 95 RON octane.

Comment: Hi @feetwet, I live in Honduras, I bought the car in Copart.